# VueJS csv Filereader

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get the input of a .csv File, after I choose it with my Html 5 input field. Therefor I use a onFileChange method and a FileReader().
Here is an example I used: http://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/ (except that I want to read the text input, and not an image file).

My Problem is, that I get an empty input on the first try, but on the second try it works. Why is that? Any ideas? (I'm a javascript beginner ;) )

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
</form>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        fileinput: ''
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChange(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createInput(files[0]);
        },
        createInput(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var vm = this;
            reader.onload = (e) => {

            vm.fileinput = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);

            console.log(this.fileinput);
        }

    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the `console.log` is not displaying anything is because `FileReader.readAsText()` is asynchronous. It completes *after* the `console.log` has executed.

You can typically deal with this by putting a watch on `fileInput` or throwing a local event using `vm.$emit` from the `onload` handler.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can handle async code using `Promise` function

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fileinput: ""
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) return;
      this.createInput(files[0]);
    },
    createInput(file) {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var vm = this;
        reader.onload = e => {
          resolve((vm.fileinput = reader.result));
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
      });

      promise.then(
        result => {
          /* handle a successful result */
          console.log(this.fileinput);
        },
        error => {
          /* handle an error */ 
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way

```js
        onFileChange: function(e) {
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = e => console.log(e.target.result);
            reader.readAsText(file);
        },
```

Reference [Creating a Vue.js File Reader Component Using the FileReader API](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-file-reader-component)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also try as below if you want separate function after promise and define in data.

```
    new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        fileinput: ""
    },
    methods: {
        readFile: function(evt) {
            const scope = this
            var promiseVar = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var file = evt.target.files[0];
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        scope.fileinput = e.target.result
                        resolve('complete');
                    };
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    reject("There must be an error");
                }
            });
            // let updateds = await Promise.all(promiseVar);
            promiseVar.then(data=>{
                scope.afterRead();
            })
        },
        afterRead:function(){
            console.log(this.fileinput)
            // write your logic for import here
        }
    }
});
```